# C - select 2D slice from 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a global 3D array declared like this:

```
TileType maps[DLVL_MAX][LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH];
```

and a function in which I'd like to name one 2D slice of this array to make things less cumbersome, i.e. something like

```
void f(int dlvl) {
    TileType level_map[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH] = &(maps[dlvl]);
    ...
}
```

At first sight this looks to me like it should be possible, since C array dimensions are ordered left to right. Yet I can't find the right expression for this. (Of course, I can just give `level_map` a `TileType*` type, but then I can't use double indexing as in `level_map[x][y]`.)

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    TileType level_map[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH] = &(maps[dlvl]);
> ```

`&(maps[dlvl])` evaluates to an address, namely the address of the `dlvl`th element of `maps`.

You cannot use an address to initialise an array, which `level_map` is.

You *could* do

```
TileType (*plevel_map)[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH] = maps[dlvl];
```

The above statement defines and initialises `plevel_map` to *point* to the `dlvl`th element of `maps`.

You would then access the elements of `dlvl`th element of `maps` like this

```
(*plevel_map)[x][y]
```

---

**Update**

What you also *could* do is

```
TileType * pplevel_map = maps[dlvl][0];
```

And then access `map[dlvl][0]`'s element like this:

```
pplevel_map[x]
```

and then do

```
pplevel_map += sizeof(**maps);
```

to seek to `maps[dlvl][1]`.

And then access `map[dlvl][1]`'s element (also) like this:

```
pplevel_map[x]
```

---

**Update^2**

To still  be able access all "level"'s elements using `[x][y]` you could do:

```
TileType (*aplevel_map)[LEVEL_WIDTH] = maps[dlvl];
```

And then access `map[dlvl]`'s element like this:

```
aplevel_map[x][y]
```

Comment: Please see correction (`TileType * pplevel_map = ...`) and update.

Comment: Sry, now it should be fine ... :}

Comment: No problem, I appreciate it! That works well, but now I can't easily do arbitrary (x, y) accesses right? I'm essentially selecting a 1D slice instead of 2D?

Comment: Finally ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
TileType level_map[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH] = &(maps[dlvl]);
```

You can't do that because `level_map` is array, and array cannot be reassigned.

What you need is `memcpy`. Given what you need to assign to `level_map` is the first element of 3D `maps` (at index 0):

```
memcpy(level_map, &maps[0], sizeof(level_map));
```

You can do the same for other elements.

---

Edit:

> I should have been clearer -- I'd like assignments to level_map elements to assign to the corresponding map element

Ok then you need to declare a pointer instead of array:

```
TileType (*level_map)[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH];  // pointer to 2D array
level_map = &maps[0]; // reassign pointer to the address of `maps` first element
```

Comment: I should have been clearer -- I'd like assignments to `level_map` elements to assign to the corresponding `map` element, so copying doesn't work for me

Comment: "*`level_map` is const pointer*", sry, but no, `levelmap` is an array.

Comment: "*`(*)level_map`*" you mean `(*level_map)`, don't you?

Comment: @alk hehe exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour

```
 TileType maps[DLVL_MAX * LEVEL_HEIGHT* LEVEL_WIDTH];
```

Now always pass maps, and levelid (guess that's what you mean), y
co-ordinate, and x co-ordinate.

```
  void foo(TileType *maps, int levelid, int x, int y)
  {
      TileType tile = BLANK;

      map[levelid * LEVEL_HEIGHT * LEVEL_WIDTH + y * LEVEL_WIDTH + x]
        = tile;
  }
```

Then the problems just disappear.
The expression is a bit cumbersome, but you soon learn to live with it.

Comment: Honest question, what's the reason for using this instead of keeping the original definition of `maps` and using `maps[levelid][x][y]`? I'm mostly trying to make this expression less cumbersome, and your answer seems to make things worse in that matter. (Don't get me wrong I appreciate the answer, I just don't really understand it)

Comment: To get into the habit of thinking of the world as tiles laid out in some arrangement in memory, rather than as constructs in some programming language..